# How to load CSS style for each shortcode in WordPress without w3 validation error?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

In previous when I develop WP shortcode then I load the CSS style depend on the shortcode params like this.

```
function test_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'foo' => 'something', 
    ), $atts );

    echo "<style>";
        .shortcode_unique_id {
            //some css property depend on shortcode
        }
    echo "</style>";
}
```

But now it did not allow to add any style tag in the body otherwise it will show w3 validation error. We need to load style in the head tag.

Please anyone tell me how to load CSS style depend on shortcode params when calling the shortcode.

Advance Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wp_register_style` and `wp_enqueue_style` to use style which is dependent on shortcode.

Main difference between `wp_enqueue_*` and respective `wp_register_*` functions, is that the first adds scripts/styles to the queue, the second prepares scripts/styles to be added.

The typical scenario of using both functions is when you want to register scripts/styles on theme init, and then enqueue them wherever necessary e.g.

```
add_action('init', 'my_register_styles');

function my_register_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'style1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style1.css' );
    wp_register_style( 'style2', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style2.css' );
    wp_register_style( 'style3', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style3.css' );
}


/*This is you shortcode function*/
function test_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'foo' => 'something', 
    ), $atts );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style1' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style2' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style3' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I want to load dynamic CSS depend on shortcode params, not pre-generate CSS files.